# Can I use std::basic_string with things that aren't character types?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've got a loop in my code that uses `std::basic_string<HANDLE>`, and then waits on it like this:

```
DWORD dwWaitResult = WaitForMultipleObjects((DWORD)handles.size(),
                                            handles.data(),
                                            FALSE, POLL_INTERVAL_MS);
```

It *works* fine, but when I turn on /W4 and /analyze, Visual C++ 2008 warns with the following (cut down and wrapped for brevity):

```
iosfwd(266) : warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory '*_First'
iosfwd(262) : while compiling class template member function
       'HANDLE *std::char_traits<_Elem>::assign(_Elem *,size_t,_Elem)'
        with [ _Elem=HANDLE ]
xstring(2155) : see reference to class template instantiation
       'std::char_traits<_Elem>' being compiled
        with [ _Elem=HANDLE ]
xstring(2148) : while compiling class template member function
       'void std::basic_string<_Elem>::_Tidy(bool,unsigned int)'
        with [ _Elem=HANDLE ]
.\MyCode.cpp(231) : see reference to class template instantiation
       'std::basic_string<_Elem>' being compiled
        with [ _Elem=HANDLE ]

iosfwd(222) : warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory '*_First1'
iosfwd(216) : while compiling class template member function
        'HANDLE *std::char_traits<_Elem>::_Copy_s
               (_Elem *,size_t,const _Elem *,size_t)'
        with [ _Elem=HANDLE ]
```

Questions:

1. Is it legal to use std::basic_string with something that's not a simple character type (i.e. `char` or `wchar_t`)?
2. If it is, what should I do to get rid of these warnings? Answering `#pragma warning(disable)` needs justification.
3. If it's not, why not? And what should I use instead?

Extra credit will be given for bearing in mind that Boost is out, and we're restricted to the STL implementation in Visual C++ 2008; the Visual C++ bits of TR1 are allowed.

Comment: just for me to know, why do you use a string of handles, and not a vector?

Comment: The call to WaitForMultipleObjects requires that the handles be contiguous in memory. At the time I wrote this code (several years ago), I didn't know that vectors were contiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, if you provide a template specialization of the `class traits` for your type.
2. Provide your specialized `class traits`. (Second template parameter of `class std::basic_string`).
3. It is. But have you thought about using `std::vector` instead of `std::basic_string`? (It does not have this traits template argument that provides string helper functions such as compare)

Answer (score 6):

whats wrong with using a std::vector instead of trying to jam that square peg into the round hole?

Answer (score 2):

Please be careful, `std::basic_string`s are never guaranteed to be contiguous memory, which `WaitForMultipleObjects` will never know about.  I highly recommend using vectors instead.

Comment: But he's using the `data()`  and not `&data[0]` to access the handles so he should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to provide a specialisation of the [char_traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/char_traits/) template for your HANDLE type.